# MySQL: Selecting from ordered results

Tags: mysql

I hope you will be able to help me, this has been giving me headaches :D

**First, a bit of context:**

Using the following table and data:

```
+-------------+---------+-------------+
| host_name   | service | last_change |
+-------------+---------+-------------+
| test.com    | PING    |  1327004398 |
| test.com    | HTTP    |  1327004536 |
| test.com    | MYSQL   |  1327004392 |
| test2.com   | PING    |  1327127720 |
| test2.com   | HTTP    |  1327004391 |
| test3.com   | PING    |  1327213842 |
| test4.com   | PING    |  1327004368 |
+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

What I'd lke to do is to print this out to a table with the host_name cell that spans the right amount of rows, a bit like so:

```
 +-------------+---------+-------------+
 | host_name   | service | last_change |
 +-------------+---------+-------------+
 |             | PING    |  1327004398 |
 | test.com    | HTTP    |  1327004536 |
 |             | MYSQL   |  1327004392 |
 +-------------+---------+-------------+
```

I am already able to do this, using a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    host_name,
    group_concat(service SEPARATOR '|') as service,
    group_concat(last_change SEPARATOR '|') as last_change,    

FROM table

GROUP BY host_name
```

And then by doing some manipulations (exploding results where pipes are found).

**The problem I have:**

I'd like to do the same thing but sort the results based on last_change. I tried to do the following:

```
SELECT
    host_name,
    group_concat(service SEPARATOR '|') as service,
    group_concat(last_change SEPARATOR '|') as last_change,    

FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY last_change DESC
) as tmp_table

GROUP BY host_name
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Changing the DESC to ASC doesn't even change the results I get.

If I run the subquery that orders the results by itself, I get the expected results except the results arent grouped by host_name (obviously since it lacks the group_concat and group by statements).

Any ideas ?

I appreciate it A LOT.

Comment: This really is not the purpose of (My)SQL. MySQL is intended to store data - showing and presenting it should be done in an external language. You'd have no trouble doing this in php, C#, java... but, it is an interesting excercise for the SQL-adept :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get exactly what you're trying to do here. Do you want results inside the group ordered, or the whole resultset?
Try this for the first case:

```
SELECT
    host_name,
    group_concat(service ORDER BY last_change DESC SEPARATOR '|') as service,
    group_concat(last_change ORDER BY last_change DESC SEPARATOR '|') as last_change
FROM table
GROUP BY host_name
```

And this for second:

```
SELECT
    host_name,
    group_concat(service SEPARATOR '|') as service,
    group_concat(last_change SEPARATOR '|') as last_change
FROM table
GROUP BY host_name
ORDER BY table.last_change
```

Comment: I am trying to get the results inside each group ordered and then the groups ordered.

Comment: Okay so I tried the second query, it almost seems to do the trick. They are almost (!?) sorted correctly, it's weird. I will try to work with that. Thanks !

Comment: Just wanted to say that the second solution ended up working fine for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is ORDER BY specifier in the group_concat parameters:

```
SELECT
    host_name,
    group_concat(service SEPARATOR '|') as service,
    group_concat(last_change ORDER BY last_change SEPARATOR '|') as last_change,    

FROM table

GROUP BY host_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried but it doesn't seem to have an effect on the results. I've tried putting ORDER BY last_change DESC and ASC and the results were exactly the same.